# The primes $2s+1$ with the constraint that $s$ satisfy certain congruence relations and Euler's idoneal numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I would like to prove the following statement:

If  $s>1$ is a positive integer and

- $s\equiv0$ modulo 3 and
- $s\equiv0$ modulo 4 and
- $2s+1$ is prime

then $2s+1 = x^{2}+24y^{2}$ for some nonzero positive integers $x$ and $y$.

For example consider the number $36$. Then $36\equiv0$ modulo 3 and $36\equiv0$ modulo 4 and $2*36+1=73$ is prime. Then we can write $73=x^{2}+24y^{2}$. Here we take $x=7$ and $y=1$. We can check that $7^{2}+24*1^{2} = 49+24=73$.

24 is an Idoneal number. According to this [paper](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~kani/papers/idoneal-f.pdf) the infinitude of primes of the form $x^{2}+24y^{2}$ has been established. Now I am certain that $12|s$ and so we can write $s=12t$ for some integer $t$. Then $2s+1 =2(12t)+1=24t+1$ which is congruent to $1$ modulo $24$. If we can establish the statement above then $24t+1=x^{2}+24y^{2}$. Compare this with [A107008](https://oeis.org/A107008) and read Sloane's comment and question.

The sequence of $s$ that solve the statement are $36,48,96,120,156,168,204,...$. This sequence is ***not*** in Sloane's database. The sequence $t$ that solve the statement above are $3,4,8,10,13,14,17,...$ which are numbers $t$ such that $24t+1$ is prime, [A107008](https://oeis.org/A111174)

Comment: Knowing Sloane, it was not a question, it was more a comment about how the sequences in the database should be labelled

Comment: Well no update to his comment in 8 years. But now we know.

Comment: I looked at your recent question on the modular group. For your interests, I think you would get some real benefit from Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms, Classical Theory and Modern Computations. I have worked up some wonderful software (C++) using just the simple suggestions in his book. http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387970370

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true, of course. The class group of discriminant $-96$ has four classes (binary forms up to equivalence)
$$ x^2 + 24 y^2, $$
$$ 4 x^2 + 4 xy+7y^2,  $$
$$ 5 x^2 + 2 xy + 5 y^2, $$
$$ 3 x^2 + 8 y^2. $$
Each form is alone in its genus, which can be seen by congruences $\pmod 3$ and $\pmod 8.$

Any prime $p$ such that $(-96|p) = 1$ can be written as one of these forms. We also need to check the primes that divide $96,$ as $2$ is not represented by a primitive form, but $3$ is. When $p \equiv 1 \pmod {24},$ we can express $p = x^2 + 24 y^2.$ When $p \equiv 7 \pmod {24},$ we can express $p = 4x^2 +4xy + 7 y^2.$ When $p \equiv 5 \pmod {24},$ we can express $p = 5x^2 +2xy + 5 y^2.$ When $p=3$ or $p \equiv 11 \pmod {24},$ we can express $p = 3x^2 + 8 y^2.$

Most of the students here seem to ask about using the geometry of numbers, Minkowski's bound and so on, to find such expressions. I like this better: given $p \neq 2,3$ and Legendre symbol   $(-96|p) = 1,$ we can solve 
$$ b^2 \equiv -96 \pmod p. $$ By insisting that this $b$ be even, possibly by switching to $p - b$ if we began with $b$ odd, we can solve
 $$ b^2 \equiv -96 \pmod {4p}. $$
This means 
$$ b^2 = -96 + 4 p t, $$ or
$$    b^2 - 4 p t = -96.$$
That is, the binary quadratic form $\langle p,b,t \rangle$ or
$$ f(x,y) = p x^2 + b x y + t y^2  $$
has discriminant $-96.$ Gauss reduction takes this to one of the four reduced forms above, and since $p \equiv 1 \pmod {24},$ it is actually equivalent to $x^2 + 24 y^2.$ The two by two reduction matrix, in $SL_2 \mathbb Z,$ inverted, tells us how to express $p = u^2 + 24 v^2.$

Comment: I think I follow the argument. I guess I should know that $(-96|2s+1)=1$? if I am off and not following let me know.  But with that said your argument looks good.  Also is it worth submitting the sequence $s=  36,48,96,120,156,168,204,....$ this is more of an opinion question but just curious. Thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez as $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8,$ we have $(-1|p) = 1,$ $(2|p ) = 1,$ and $(3 | p) = 1.$ So $(32|p) = 1$ and $(-96|p) = 1.$

Comment: Cool! The origin of the question comes from a finite geometry of arrangements.